# How to read a .TDAT file?

Tags: c#, .net, readfile

I have a software that saves the data in a .tdat file. Now I want to access the data with my own program ( .net).

The data stored in it should be strings. When I open the file in the editor, I only see some weard symbols, but in some places I can see the text that I typed.

I hope you can help me and thank you very much !!!

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: besides some standards (pdf, xml, ...) everyone can create their own file format and call it whatever they want. Therefore you'll find countless custom formats with .dat or similar extensions. You can ask the manufacturer or, if it's open source, check the source code on github or similar to find out more.

Comment: What software creates this file?

Comment: it´s a private software of my company.

Comment: You ask on SO how you can read a file format of your own company?

Comment: Yes :D the problem is i dont really like the standard software and we do not get any support from the developer to change the software ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution?

```
ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
objectToSerialize = (ObjectToSerialize)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
return objectToSerialize;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. whats the namespace of ObjectToSerialize ? my visualstudio does not detect it.

Comment: try one of these.
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Comment: Sadly it does not work.

`using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace tdatopener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
            Stream stream = File.Open("file.tdat", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            objectToSerialize = (ObjectToSerialize)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serializing-objects-in-C-Sharp/
Please refer to this link. It describes about serialization and deserialization well.